# Numpy: integrate dimension from one array into another

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays *a* (shape=`a, b, c, d, e`) and *b* (shape=`a, x, b`), I'd like to include the dimension `x` of *b* into *a*, so that a new array *c* results in a shape=`a, x, b, c, d, e`. The values of *b* should be distributed evenly:

- `c.sum(1) == a`
- `b.sum(1) == a.sum(axis=(2, 3, 4)) == c.sum(axis=(1, 3, 4, 5)`

Is there any smart way of doing this is a few lines with numpy or is it necessary to iterate over all values of `b[x]` manually?

My current solution:

```
for a, x, b in zip(*_b_.nonzero()):
    tot = _a_[a, b].sum()
    for c, d, e in zip(*_a_[a, b].nonzero()):
        val = _b_[a, a, b]
        frac = _a_[a, b, c, d, e] / tot
        _c_[a, x, b, c, d, e] = val * frac
```

Comment: `c = a[:,None,...] + b[:,:,:,None,None,None]` should form a new matrix with the right dimensions.  Scaling `a` or `b` might satisfy your sum conditions.  I haven't studied them enough to say for sure.

Comment: I've updated the description with some sample code. I don't think adding _a_ and _b_ will work...

Comment: Please do us all a favor and don't use the same variable names for dimensions and variables.  It makes your code and descriptions devilishly hard to read.

Comment: I can't test it, but I don't think you need a loop for `_c_,d,e` part.  `c[a,x,b,...]=val/tot*_a_[a,b,...]`

Comment: @Daniel F: Sorry, this wasn't on purpose. I only realised the ambiguity after I added the code, but it was too late to fix this as some people had already commented...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this in 3 lines, but first some remarks about my approach:

- For a better notation I will use capital letters for matrices, and small letters for indices. So we have `A[a,b,c,d,e]` and `B[a,x,b]` as input.
- According to your code, `C` is the same for all `x`, so we don't really need that axis for the calculation (if required, you can add it as a new dimension and and duplicate the entries afterwards).
- `B[a,a,b]` can be contracted by taking the diagonal along the first two axes.
- `tot` is a sum over indices `c,d,e`, we can store this in a precalculated array `Tot[a,b]`
- to be able to use `numpy.einsum` in the final step, I will first take the inverse `Tot = 1/Tot`

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy

# generate some example input
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
d = 5
e = 6
x = 7

A = numpy.arange(a*b*c*d*e).reshape((a,b,c,d,e))
B = numpy.arange(a*x*b).reshape((a,x,b))
C = numpy.zeros((a,x,b,c,d,e))

# solution by orange
for a, x, b in zip(*B.nonzero()):
    tot = A[a, b].sum()
    for c, d, e in zip(*A[a, b].nonzero()):
        val = B[a, a, b]
        frac = A[a, b, c, d, e] / tot
        C[a, x, b, c, d, e] = val * frac

# new solution
B2 = numpy.diagonal(B, axis1=0, axis2=1).transpose() # contract B_aab -> B2_ab
Tot = 1/numpy.sum(A, (2,3,4))   # contract \sum_cde A_abcde -> 1 / Tot_ab
C2 = numpy.einsum('ab,abcde,ab->abcde',B2,A,Tot)

# compare (should print x times True)
for i in range(C.shape[1]):
    C_ = C[:,i,:,:,:]
    print(numpy.all(numpy.isclose(C_,C2)))
```

Edit: If `numpy.einsum()` is too slow for you, you can implement the last step in Cython with `for` loops.